# NullPointerException when timepicker +/- button clicked in android

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, timepicker

I get a NullPointerException when i click on timepicker +/- button . My App supports android 2.2 and above. The exception I get is :

```
07-01 01:50:28.094: E/AndroidRuntime(31676): java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.widget.TimePicker.updateInputState(TimePicker.java:695)
at android.widget.TimePicker.access$000(TimePicker.java:58)
at android.widget.TimePicker$2.onValueChange(TimePicker.java:155)
at android.widget.NumberPicker.notifyChange(NumberPicker.java:1822)
at android.widget.NumberPicker.setValueInternal(NumberPicker.java:1608)
at android.widget.NumberPicker.changeValueByOne(NumberPicker.java:1636)
```

This happens when i add a Flyout menu from the left. If that Menu is removed, I dont get this exception. Please let me know how i could correct this error.

This is my code:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    timePicker = (TimePicker) view.findViewById(R.id.tpTimer);

    timePicker.setCurrentHour(0);
    timePicker.setCurrentMinute(0);

    timePicker.setIs24HourView(true);
    Button btnStart = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
    btnStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
    timePicker.getCurrentHour();
}}
```

Comment: Can you highlight what is on Line 695 in timepicker

Comment: That is a framework error. its not in my file.